# Well Formed String using Stack and HashMap

Tags: java

Examples of well formed and not well formed strings are:

```
1.  “A3{DJE(DG[FF]K)WA65}”      - well formed
2.  “BBB[BM98{WJHG]333}”    - Not well formed
3.  “CBY(DDD(WKLP)BEHOP”    - Not well formed
```

Supported brackets are {}, [] and ()

Here is what I am trying to do and it's always returning false for some reason.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Stack;

public class WellFormedStringCheck {



    public static boolean isWellFormed(String input){

        if(input == null) return true;

        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();

        Map<Character,Character> map = new HashMap<Character,Character>();

        map.put('{', '}');
        map.put('(', ')');
        map.put('[', ']');



        for(int i = 0 ; i < input.length(); i++){

                char s = input.charAt(i);

                if(s == '[' || s == '{' || s == '(' )
                    stack.push(s);
                if(s == ']' || s == '}' || s == ')'){

                    if(stack.isEmpty()) return false;

                    if(map.get(s) != stack.pop()); return false;


                }

            }

        if(!stack.isEmpty()) return false;

         return true;


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      System.out.println(isWellFormed("A3{DJE(DG[FF]K)WA65}"));

    }

}
```

Could anyone tell me what's wrong with the above approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a silly mistake, and you built your reference maps for parentheses, braces, and brackets *backwards*.  Here is how you were originally building the map:

```
map.put('{', '}');
map.put('(', ')');
map.put('[', ']');
```

But you were looking up *closing* parentheses, braces, and brackets in the map, when the keys were actually the opening characters instead.  This was returning `null` and causing your method to return `false`.

Here is the complete code for your method:

```
public static boolean isWellFormed(String input) {
    if (input == null) return true;

    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
    Map<Character,Character> map = new HashMap<Character,Character>();

    map.put('}', '{');
    map.put(')', '(');
    map.put(']', '[');

    for (int i=0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char s = input.charAt(i);

        if (s == '[' || s == '{' || s == '(') {
            stack.push(s);
        }
        if (s == ']' || s == '}' || s == ')') {
            if (map.get(s) != stack.pop()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I tested your code with this change in IntelliJ and it seems to run without any problems.

Comment: It's still returning false after making changes.

Comment: OK I'll post the entire method.  You have another bug there.

Comment: I copied and pasted your method and getting `Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
 at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)
 at java.util.Stack.pop(Stack.java:84)
 at com.ak.string.WellFormedStringCheck.isWellFormed(WellFormedStringCheck.java:31)
 at com.ak.string.WellFormedStringCheck.main(WellFormedStringCheck.java:45)
` in Eclipse IDE

Comment: Also, this will only work as long as your opening and closing characters have an ASCII value below 128. Change this line: `if (map.get(s) != stack.pop())` to `if (!map.get(s).equals(stack.pop()))`. Reason: autoboxing creates java.lang.Character objects, and you shouldn't compare references with `==` and `!=`. It only works now because there is an optimization for characters <128.

Answer (score 1):

Though you got some answer, you may also like solution using Deque, Set & Map.

```
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {

    private static Map<Character, Character> map = new HashMap<>();
    private static Set<Character> brackets = new HashSet<>();

    static {
        map.put('{', '}');
        map.put('(', ')');
        map.put('[', ']');

        for (Map.Entry<Character, Character> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            brackets.add(entry.getKey());
            brackets.add(entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String exp : new String[] { "A3{DJE(DG[FF]K)WA65}", "BBB[BM98{WJHG]333}", "CBY(DDD(WKLP)BEHOP" })
            System.out.printf("%b\t%s%n", validate(exp), exp);
    }

    private static boolean validate(String exp) {
        boolean valid = true;
        Deque<Character> deque = new LinkedList<Character>();
        for (char c : exp.toCharArray())
            if (brackets.contains(c))
                deque.add(c);
        char l, r;
        while (!deque.isEmpty()) {
            l = deque.removeFirst();
            try {
                r = deque.removeLast();
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                valid = !valid;
                break;
            }
            if (valid) {
                if (r != map.get(l)) {
                    valid = !valid;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return valid;
    }

}
```

Comment: Works well. Could you explain me why did you use `map.put()` method inside a static block?

Comment: As you can see, the map & set are static, I used `static` block to fill values in it, since `static` blocks are executed only once.

Comment: But do you think that it is really required to use static block?